# What git tool has a similar Perforce P4V feature

Tags: linux, git, perforce

I often use the Perforce P4V client and like the Diff > Diff Against Previous Revision feature available with right-click on the checked-out file. I think P4V launches the diff tool, displaying the differences. There are also two useful buttons to go to next/previous diff.

What linux git tool has a similar feature ?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're looking for a clickable GUI that has a button to do this, not for a command-line command to do this? (I tend to avoid the clicky GUIs and have no recommendations here.)

Comment: I would appreciate it if i could do the same with a command line tool.

Comment: Git can really only go backwards from some particular commit. Running `git log <starting-point> -- <path>` will show you commits that modified the specified `<path>` with respect to their immediate parent commit. You can get a lot more specific with `git log -G` and `git log -S`, which search for a specific *change* as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitExtensions can do something similar to this